# how to place an image PNG containing a barcode generated by Aspose, and place it upper right in PDF document

Tags: aspose, aspose.pdf

I generated a QR code DataMatrix one, I used in a rectangle the cordinates:
LLx= 6
LLY= 40
URX= 26
URY= 120
and I used a Matrix class with these exactly cordinates except the second and third argument 0 and 0
It was good, later I had a requirement to rotate it and place it in upper right of the document.
I don't get really the coordiantes system of Aspose.
What I tried is to increase in all combinations these rectangle values, however the images it moves but gets bigger, I just want it to move with same dimension in upper right and rotate
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Aspose.PDF follows the coordinating system where coordinates start from lower-left corner of the page. In order to move the image to upper-right, you need to increase the values of LLX and LLY. However, if you still face any issue, please share a complete code snippet with sample input file(s). We will test the scenario in our environment and address it accordingly. You can also create a post in Aspose.PDF forum (https://forum.aspose.com/c/pdf). This is Asad Ali and I work as Developer Evangelist at Aspose.

Comment: @AsadAli thanks for your reply, still not clear, increase them how? shall i add same value for both? why if increase only one the size of photo change? what represents URX and URY? what is the unit used?

Comment: @Kahlil the URX and URY represent upper-right X and upper-right Y respectively. Moreover, the image which is being drawn will start its position from lower-left X and lower-left Y (LLX/LLY) and end at URX and URY. The size of the image will depend upon the distance between lower-left and upper-right corner values. The unit of the measurement is point with 72 points = 1 inch.

Comment: @AsadAli so for moving the picture (rectangle) as you said we have to increase LLx and LLy, does that not change the size then ? if we don't ncrease as well others?

Comment: we apologize if our comment caused any confusion. As shared in our later comments, you need to change the values of all coordinates accordingly. However, in order to investigate properly, we need your sample document and sample input image along with code snippet that you are using and expected output. We will surely proceed further to assist you accordingly. You can also post in our forum with the files or upload them somewhere and share the link with us.